# How to create a vertical clickable divider|line in bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a layout, left 24% is sidebar menu, right 75% is main content, between the left and right is a vertical divider or line 1% which is clickable. 
By clicking this line, left part will be hidden. and the line will move to the left end of the screen, and right part will become 99%.
If click this line again, it will become 24% left and 75% right again.

How can I create this kind of vertical clickable line?

I just want to know the vertical clickable line itself, rest part(click=>resize left/right part) is OK, I know how to do it.

I want to know how to draw this line in HTML? using div? using a vertical line image? or ??

Thank you all very much, so it is created by CSS :)

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: I completely have no idea how to create such kind of vertical clickable line. By using talbe? or <div>? I can do the the click part by JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simple solution for you. Hopefully it does the trick.

```js
$('.vd').on('click', function(){
  
  $('.left').toggleClass('not-visible');
  $('.right').toggleClass('all-visible');
  
});
```

```css
html,body{
  height: 100%;  
}

.left, .vd, .right{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

.left{
  width: 24%;  
  background: #f00;
}
.vd{
  width: 1%;  
  background: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.right{
  width: 75%;  
  background: #f0f;
}
.animated{
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000); 
   -moz-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000); 
     -o-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000); 
        transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);  
}
.not-visible{
  width: 0%;  
}
.all-visible{
  width: 99%;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="left animated">Left content</div>
<div class="vd"></div>
<div class="right animated">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution with **Flexbox** and **Jquery**

```js
$('.right span').click(function() {
  $('.left').toggleClass('hide');
  $(this).toggleClass('bold');
});
```

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.left {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

.right {
  flex: 75%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 3px;
  background: black;
}

.hide {
  flex: 0 0 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bold {
  width: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right"><span tabindex="0"></span>Right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an example that i made;

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="left">
left lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
<div id="divider">

</div>
<div id="right">
right content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  height:300px;
}
#left{
  width: 23%;
  float:left;
  transition:all .4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition:all .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all .4s ease-in-out;
}
.toggle-left {
  width:0% !important;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#divider {
  width:2%;
  float:left;
  background:#000;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#right {
  width:75%;
  float:left;
  transition:all .4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition:all .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all .4s ease-in-out;
}
.toggle-right {
  width: 98% !important;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#divider',function(){
    $("#left").toggleClass('toggle-left');   
    $("#right").toggleClass('toggle-right');
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4b1p8nse/1/

Answer (score 1):

Though you already got working solutions, here is one with bootstrap. Basically I have used left border of main content div as vertical trigger line and overlayed it with div to provide with pointer (hand) cursor.

```js
$(".nav-switch").on("click", function() {
  var $t = $(this),
    v = !!$t.data("visible");
  $t.data("visible", !v);
  $("div.nav-col").toggleClass("hidden");
  if (v) {
    /*currently showing nav*/
    $("div.main-col").removeClass("col-xs-9").addClass("col-xs-12");
  } else {
    $("div.main-col").removeClass("col-xs-12").addClass("col-xs-9");
  }
});
```

```css
.main-col {
  background-color: #d39;
}
.nav-switch {
  border-left: 10px blue solid;
}
.nav-switch-pointer {
  border: 0px dotted yellow;
  width: 10px!important;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 nav-col">
      this is navigation column
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9 main-col">
      <div class="row fl-rt nav-switch" data-visible="1">
        <div class="nav-switch-pointer">
          &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          this is right column.
          <br/>click on blue line to hide/show nav
          <br/>this div will adjust its width accordingly
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <br/>wow!
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```